# PDF being generated and then disappears [error message below]

Tags: errors, miktex

The error message reads"Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason: PK font futr8r could not be created. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: XXX/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help."

I'm trying to compile a large project of mine, and this is the issue I'm currently facing. I don't see any other particular errors that could correspond to this, as they're just warnings. If you need more info , let me know.

Comment: MiKTeX tries to make bitmap fonts (that's what `makepk` does), this means pdflatex can't find the path to the type 1 fonts. Open `MiKTeX console` (as user and as administrator) and in the `Tasks` menu, click on `Refresh font map files`.

Comment: @Bernard I ended up reinstalling MikTex, and it must have had the same effect. Thanks anyway

Comment: But dis you refresh the Font map files?

Comment: Also, just in case (;-)), is the `fourier` package installed?